# How to set onClickListener() for view of Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I want to catch user interaction with a spinner like onCLickListener. Do to the 'don't call onClickListener() on AdapterView' error I found recommendations that you should override a constructer with a custom spinner to set onClickListener() on the view the spinner creates.

Tried that:

```
public class MySpinner extends Spinner {

public static final String TAG = "MyApp";

public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.temp_systems, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    TextView spinner_text = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    OnClickListener spinnerOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Should do something!");
        }

    };

    spinner_text.setOnClickListener(spinnerOnClickListener);

    setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

but when I try to include this in a layout I get a crash on failing to inflate this item.

To clarify here, onItemClickListener fires when the user clicks an item in the dropdown menu, not when the spinner is collapsed. I need to intercept after the initial spinner is clicked but before it creates the dropdown menu.

Comment: Can you show the error/crashlog it gives?

Comment: I think you should take a look at spinner example. Plus post more info on your layout and how you are setting the view/inflating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they might mean is to `Override` the `setOnItemClickListener` and then call that in the constructor. So in your `mySpinner` class you would need to add: [notice it is called on ITEM click listener, that might also be part of your issue]

```
@Override
    public void setOnItemClickListener(
            android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener l) {
        super.setOnItemClickListener(l);
//... do action here that you want to happen when item in spinner is clicked
    }
```

Dunno if that will fix your issue but I hope it helps. Good Luck.

also it might be worthwhile to possibly use

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
     //do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are needing to extend Spinnner or why you are assigning a click listener on the TextView. You should be assigning a selection listener on the spinner. As per the Spiner example consider:

1) Having a layout with a Spinner control

2) Having a 'Spinner' member of your activity

3) Inflate the layout via `setContentView` and then assign the spinner member via `findViewById`

4) Set the adapter for the spinner and call `setOnItemSelectedListener` on your spinner to assign a selection listener

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnTouchListener instead of OnClickListener, which is not available for Spinner.